# Display layout problem with 3 monitor screens

Tags: release-loki, display

I am not new to linux.
First of all i have to say that i've installed it on my work laptop (sysadmin) which i use with 2 additional monitors.

The layout is:

- left monitor - additional monitor - clockwise rotated
- center monitor - laptop's build-in monitor - no rotation
- right monitor - additional monitor - no rotation.

The problem is that in System settings -> Displays i can arrange this layout BUT i cannot stick together the left and the center monitors (pic attached).
If i move the left monitor so that it is sticked to the center one the "Apply" button remains grayed out.
This is pretty annoying because the gap between the 2 monitors is pretty big.

Image:
https://owc.darman.ro/index.php/s/codAbnH9W4YelhR

Can i configure the monitor layout from somewhere else or how can i fix this?

Comment: That link no longer works. can you post an updated one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe it's been this long and none of the _______'s at elementary HQ haven't fixed this.

Try this:
http://www.calgorithms.com/blog/2014/07/30/fixing-multiple-monitor-position-in-ubuntu-gnome-14-dot-04/

Comment: You are a real life saver, thanks man. With a little tuning this worked (i've added the "rotation" option in the script). Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help out. elementary is the closest we have now to a Mac-like environment, I only wish this project would be embraced by some of the dot com billionaires and totally juiced up. I have watched the Linux desktop world languish at the hands of souless sullen geeks who have zero style skills in the Linux desktop arena, and elementary gives me hope that we can have a great desktop. It is very frustrating to see that some of these most basic of tweaks have not been addressed.

Comment: https://elementary.io/get-involved

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.